# Connecting different models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Cart
  has_many :line_items
end

class Product
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :carts
  belongs_to :products
end
```

Example: I am an admin creating Tourist package. Assume it has attributes
Title: Description Location Price
Apartments
Title  Rooms  Description Picture 
Limos
Title Driver Color

I learned that They should be linked to Product model in order customers can add them to the cart and purchase.

But how to link  Should I create those models or make category, but they have different attributes.

Let's say I have 100 different categories. And each category has totally different attributes. Should I create 100 models or is there any best way of doing it?

Example Amazon.com
Departments Baby Beauty Books and more.
Baby category can have age, sex attributes
But Books isbn, publisher,
They are in Category model but have different attributes.
Does it mean I have to create model Baby, model Book, model Beauty.
Or I am missing something

Comment: what are some examples of categories with different attributes?

Comment: Would you like to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of meta data.

Product has_many product_meta_items

ProductMetaItem would have:

attributes :product_id, category_id, :label, :value

it's likely that you'll want to store the meta which needs to be created somewhere so you'll also need

ProductCategory has_many meta_types

MetaType
 attributes :product_category_id, :label

these can then be iterated over to create a dynamic form for the Product including (nested) meta_items.